# Confused about Amazon compute pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Inspecting my usage for February 2014 in I do not understand how 594 instance hours were used as I have not used my deployed application for most of most of February. I have since deleted the app, will this guarantee it is not incurring any more costs ? The app I deployed is process intensive but the max amount of total CPU processing was 30 mins at 100% , could this have incurred this kind of cost : 594 elastic compute hours ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ec2 instance has to be in a stopped state to not get billed. If it is running then you are getting charged. It has nothing to do with whether your app is running or not.

Source from AWS FAQ:

> Q: What defines billable EC2 instance-hours?
>
> Instance-hours are billed for any time your instances are in a
>   “running” state. If you no longer wish to be charged for your
>   instance, you must "stop" or "terminate" the instance to avoid being
>   billed for additional instance-hours. Billing starts when an instance
>   transitions into the running state.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/

Comment: so according to this logic my app has been in a running state for 594 / 24 = 24.75 days

Comment: The EC2 instance, yes. If you have multiple E2C instances that would also matter. You can view the state of your EC2 instance in the EC2 dashboard, it'll say if it is "running" or not.